# Property 'width' does not exist on type 'false | ImageStyle | RegisteredStyle<ImageStyle> |

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm trying to put things in order with typing in the project and I can't figure out how to fix the error `Property 'width' does not exist on type 'false | ImageStyle | RegisteredStyle<ImageStyle> | RecursiveArray<ImageStyle | Falsy | RegisteredStyle<ImageStyle>>'.   Property 'width' does not exist on type 'false'.`

I have property `style` and in this property I have property `width` which I get from parent component by props:

```
style={{
  width: style?.width ? style?.width : width * 0.8,
}}
```

I have tried to create additional interface with this property:

```
interface AdditionalImageStyle {
  width: number,
}
```

and add it to existing interface:

```
interface ImageProps {
  style?: StyleProp<ImageStyle> | AdditionalImageStyle;
}
```

but it doesn't work. Also I have tried to resolve it like this:

```
style?.width as AdditionalImageStyle
```

How I can tell typescript that property `width` in `style` must be of type `number`?

Comment: Could you create a small [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-xlpsg) that reproduces your issue?

Comment: I created sandbox, but while I was creating it I understand the problem, and now it works fine, I just didn't need that `StyleProp<ImageStyle>` for my purposes `AdditionalImageStyle` interface is enough. I don't know why but when I use `StyleProp<ImageStyle> | AdditionalImageStyle` typescript reads properties only from `StyleProp<ImageStyle>`. Thanks.